How to add XML to an odt file using OdfPy and Pandoc?
I'm working on a project generating ODT files with Python.
I'm parsing user input (markdown) using Pandoc to convert it into pieces of OpenDocument content. Then, I want to merge this content to an existing OpenDocument element from the OdfPy library.
However, it seems that the OdfPy lib only takes plain text as input (see code example below).
I'm thinking there must be some lower level methods directly handling XML that I could use, though the documentation is quite sparse and I couldn't find them.
myDoc = OpenDocument()
myDoc.text.addElement(P("Some user input"))

Instead of "Some user input", I have XML content generated by Pandoc that resembles this :
'<text:p text:style-name="Text_20_body">Some user input</text:p>\r\n'

Is it possible to add the above string to my OpenDocument object using OdfPy methods ?
If that matters, I'm using Python 3.6, odfpy 1.4.0, pypandoc 1.3.2

I don't know about adfpy, but in plain pandoc, you can use raw xml snippets.
